# No data receiving from AGWPE

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to read data from a socket connected to an AGWP Engine. It's a simple TCP/IP server which is sending frames over a socket on port 8000 by default.

```
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Connect("10.0.0.2", 8000);
    socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;

    while(true)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(socket.Connected + " - " + socket.Available);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[36];
         int read = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None, out SocketError error);

         Console.WriteLine(read);
    }
```

This is a sample of my code, which i use in various other projects. But i'm not receiving anything on the buffer.

When i run the application [AGWTracker](https://www.sv2agw.com/ham/agwtracker.htm), i see incoming data correctly. I did found a [agwpe .net port](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=agwpeport) which is also not working.

According to the response i got from socket.Available, no data should be present inside the stream. Is there any other way to check if data is available? Is there another class which can be used instead of socket or socketClient?

Comment: then there is nothing to read; are you sure you completed the outbound message, including any terminators?

Comment: this was indeed the problem. I had to enable some monitoring frame on the socket. Which was not well documented in the documentation i had previous. thx for this hint which made me looking for the good documentation of this protocol

Answer (score 1):

you've passed `0` as the maximum number of bytes to receive; so... you'll always receive zero bytes; the 3rd parameter should typically be `buffer.Length` (since you're using `0` as the `offset`)

Zero length reads are actually incredibly useful sometimes (so you can wait for data without needing buffer space), which is why it doesn't flag this as an error.

Comment: thx for the quick answer, when i change this to buffer.Length i got an timeout exception. So i guess the socket is not receiving anything. (socket.Available returns always 0)